# hungarian algorithm's graph in python

Tags: python, hungarian-algorithm

I am trying to implement hungarian algorithm in my project, but I don't understand why it gives a endless loop...I have tried with an other bibartite graph and it works. So I want to know what's wrong with my graph `G`

```
 from hungarian_algorithm import algorithm
 G={
'agt2': {'Commentaire':200,'PhotoProfil': 8, 'PhotoSupp': 10, 'Prenom': 0}, 
'coco': {'Commentaire': 300, 'PhotoProfil': 200, 'PhotoSupp': 300, 'Prenom': 300}
 }
res=algorithm.find_matching(G,matching_type='max',return_type='list')
print(res)
```

Comment: It is a hungarian_algorithm object

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular package, it may be a bug in that implementation. Perhaps you could use a more established implementation like [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html#scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment)?

Comment: You could try your graph in this online version of the algorithm to substantiate it's not your graph: [hungarian algorithm](http://www.hungarianalgorithm.com/solve.php).  It also provides step by step description of the solution.

Comment: The problem is not my graph! I'll use scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.Thank you

Comment: @TojoRandrianarimanana did SciPy finally work for you? I'm in a very similar position and I realized that the Hungarian-algorithm library wasn't working for some input graphs. I wish to switch to SciPy too, so just wanted to ask if you got it to work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph is fine, it's probably a bug in the implementation of that package. As pointed out in my comment you can use [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html#scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment) from [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) instead.

For example

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

# solve the assignment problem
G = np.array([[200, 8,   10,  0],
              [300, 200, 300, 300]])
row_indices, col_indices = linear_sum_assignment(G, maximize=True)

# print results
row_names = ['agt2', 'coco']
col_names = ['Commentaire', 'PhotoProfil', 'PhotoSupp', 'Prenom']
edges = [((row_names[r], col_names[c]), G[r, c]) for r, c in zip(row_indices, col_indices)]
print(edges)
```

prints

```
[(('agt2', 'Commentaire'), 200), (('coco', 'PhotoSupp'), 300)]
```

Comment: Ok, exuse me, I'm new member :D